# Reflection : get static property name

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I need to get the property name of a static property dynamically called as a parameter.
Here is my Portable Class Library code:

```
public partial class Test
    {
        public Test()
        {
            string staticPropName = Test.GetPropName(Test.Row); // result must be "Row" without additional string
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("propName=" + staticPropName);
        }

        public static int Row { get; set; }

        public static string GetPropName(object Property)
        {
            return "Row"; // using reflection
        }
    }
```

I don't know the name of the property and I don't want to define it with an additional string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do that - when function is called it gets value of the property and have no idea where this value come from. Your sample is equivalent of

```
     string staticPropName = Test.GetPropName(42);
```

which nobody would expect to return name.

You can try to require `Expression` as argument so you can actually inspect what method get called with like following staring point (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011109/how-do-you-get-the-name-of-the-property):

```
public static string GetPropName<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> expression)
{ 
    MemberExpression body = (MemberExpression)expression.Body;
    return body.Member.Name;
}

string staticPropName = Test.GetPropName(()=> Test.Prop);
```

Note that you need checks to make sure expression is just one you expect and not something like `() => Test + 42` or more complex one and report nice error.

Comment: Just to expand, the accepted answer in this question shows an example of how to inspect the expression and how to call GetPropName method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011109/how-do-you-get-the-name-of-the-property

Comment: @DavidKhaykin - thanks - I've linked/inlined sample.

Comment: Maybe on .Net future release !